# Does anyone know what font this is?

Tags: font-identification

Does anyone know what font this is in the image below? [image]

Answer (score 1):

It's Orgreave Extended Normal, but stretched in a drawing program. This is the original non-stretched version:

[image]

It's in public domain and can be used commercially without paying.